# Date Time Picker UI is not working properly bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using date time picker of bootstrap calendar is coming fine but Its UI is not working properly after selecting the date.

[image]

[image]

this is my html file

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./css/datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
 <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:130px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>



    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> -->
        <script src="./js/lib/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/lib/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/lib/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my script for ui

```
 $(function() {

        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
             viewMode: 'years'
        });


    });
```

console error

[image]

file [image]description

[image]

directory structure

[image]

Comment: Any console errors? You have **id = datetimepicker9** but in jQuery you have  **#datetimepicker1** is this a Typo?

Comment: @DawoodAwan i have changed that mistakenly i have some different js and i have also added the console error

Comment: the problem appears after selecting a date? do you get any console errors after selecting date?

Comment: You are clearly missing the font files, but there must be something else amiss.

Comment: @DawoodAwan Yes after selecting date this problem appears , and no console error after selecting date  rather than above three problem appears in console while loading page itself

Comment: which datetime picker are you using? Please share URL of documentation

Comment: @DawoodAwan i have downloaded the js and css file and kept it in local directory

Comment: I mean where did you download the Plugin from? is it this one? http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/

Comment: @DawoodAwan i have downloaded js file from here https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/tree/master/src/js

Comment: This library has been updated now. It requires the latest jQuery (2.1) and Moment.JS and you don't need the **pt-BR.js** http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/

Comment: @DawoodAwan thx for the solution its working i have one more problem if you see in calender instead of arrow mark rectangular box is coming can you please tell why this is happening

Comment: Because the fonts are not loading. you have to have a fonts folder with glyphicons, if you download latest bootstrap fonts folder should be there

Comment: @DawoodAwan Hi Awan , i have put the  glyphicons but still i am getting the 404 error

Answer (score 0):

I would try two things:

1. Call the datepicker for the Input, not the `<div>`

Like this:

`<input type='text' class="form-control" id="datetimepicker1">`

2. Besides the 1st point, as the console error sugest maybe you should check the relative paths of the scripts.

If your main file its above the src folder, you could try to redirect the links like `src="src/main/webapp/js/<your script file>"`, and if the file its below you should try `"../"` to go up one level, or simply `src="/src/main/..."` to start from the root folder.

Try that, because the "./" could be tricky in DOCTYPE HTML documents.